# Database design for admin role

Tags: database, database-design, web-applications, relational-database, system-design

I am desiging an app that have users who can write different posts(text, file image etc.). In order these posts to be made visible to the other users, there should be an admin who will validate that the content of the post is correct and will give permission for the publishing of the post. I am using relational database.
What is the best way to design the database in order to support this feature?

Comment: You can have a status on a post (preliminary, approved), or you could have separate preliminary posts and approved posts tables.

Comment: Or separate posts and approved posts tables, or separate posts and preliminary posts tables.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should create posts table having status_flag(value 0 and 1)
   column.
2. If some one posts it, keep status 0 by default. When Admin approves
       it, change status to 1.

So single table will suffice all your need, you don't need to create dependency on tables resulting into better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mohsen said, having a `status_flag` column would work. I would also add a foreign key in the `posts` table, that references the Id of the moderator. That way, you can track who approved each post. Additionally, you may want a third column, a timestamp called `date_approved` for more tracking purposes.